# NameError with class variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

Soppose such a minimal code:

```
class Dog:
    kind = 'canine'        
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name   

class TestDog(Dog):
    print(kind)
```

It comes by error:

```
NameError: name 'kind' is not defined
```

Since the class attribute `kind` is inherited universally,
why NameError reported?

Comment: Use Dog.kind to access the variable `kind`

Comment: BTW, your `TestDog` class is a bit odd. We don't normally put executable code like that into a class definition outside a method, except maybe to initialize a class attribute.